# I have multiple variables which sometimes have the same value, but not always, how to specify which part of the function to use python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
AWomen = BWomen = CWomen = DWomen = EWomen = 1
def pointscalcwomen(value):
    if value == AWomen:
        print("AWomen")
        if value < 12:
            womenspoints = 105 - 5 * (int(AWomen))
        elif value < 61:
            womenspoints = 61 - AWomen
        else:
            womenspoints = 1
    elif value == BWomen:
        print("BWomen")
        if value < 7:
            womenspoints = 80 - 5 * (int(BWomen))
        elif value < 56:
            womenspoints = 56 - BWomen
        else:
            womenspoints = 1
    elif value == CWomen:
        print("CWomen")
        if value < 51:
            womenspoints = 51 - CWomen
        else:
            womenspoints = 1
    elif value == DWomen:
        print("DWomen")
        if value < 31:
            womenspoints = 31 - DWomen
        else:
            womenspoints = 1
    elif value == EWomen:
        print("EWomen")
        if value < 12:
            womenspoints = 105 - 5 * (int(EWomen))
        elif value < 61:
            womenspoints = 61 - EWomen
        else:
            womenspoints = 1
    return womenspoints
for row in reader:
    if "A" in row[0]:
        points = pointscalcwomen(AWomen)
        print(points)
        AWomen = AWomen + 1
    elif "B" in row[0]:
        points = pointscalcwomen(BWomen)
        print(points)
        BWomen = BWomen + 1
    elif "C" in row[0]:
        points = pointscalcwomen(CWomen)
        print(points)
        CWomen = CWomen + 1
    elif "D" in row[0]:
        points = pointscalcwomen(DWomen)
        print(points)
        DWomen = DWomen + 1
    elif "E" in row[0]:
        points = pointscalcwomen(EWomen)
        print(points)
        EWomen = EWomen + 1
```

AWomen/BWomen etc. is category as Category A women, I have AMen, BMen etc. but with the men I am unlikely to ever encounter this problem.

However, I am facing the problem that if A is never in row[0], then the first B will get 100 points, not 75 etc.

This is because at that point `value == AWomen == BWomen`, is there a way to get around this. I have thought of changing my code to something like:

```
elif "B" in row[0]:
    A = 10000
    points = pointscalcwomen(BWomen)
    B = B + 1
```

This would make the script work most of the time as in the CSV row[0] will generally follow the pattern:

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
```

However, if there is the case where it is:

```
A
A
B
A
B
B
```

then it would not work as the A in the fourth row who was beaten by a B would get 1 point instead of 90.

Comment: It is hard to understand what the code actually **should** do. What meaning have "AWomen", "BWomen",..., "A", "B",...? "pointscalcwomen()" also checks "value" against "Cw" (what is that?) and "D" which seems not logical (but I may be wrong).

Comment: @MichaelButscher see updated code and question.

Comment: In the new version you increment "A", "B",... but never define an initial value.

Comment: I do not really understand what the code should do yet but maybe you should call `pointscalcwomen` with a string like `"A"` or `"B"`, check against that and instead of `value` use the appropriate `AWomen`, `BWomen`,... for calculation.